# Как назвать искреннего ханжу?

Tags: лексикон, значения

Определение ханжи таково:

> Тот, кто притворно набожен, добродетелен; лицемер.

А как назвать человека, который непритворно, а искренне набожен, добродетелен? Он лезет ко всем с нравоучениями, упрекает в безнравственности. Он так же напрягает в общении, как ханжа, но он верит в то, что говорит.

Есть ли для этого какое-то емкое слово?

Comment: I'm tempted to say [моралфаг](http://lurkmore.to/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3).

Comment: @GSerg  I doubt моралфаг is sincere )))

Comment: назойливый зануда, читающий всем мораль.

Comment: Моралфаг — слишком жаргонно и грубо, а вариант Ольги все-таки не емок. Про назойливого зануду сам тоже думал.

Comment: "Моралфаг — слишком жаргонно" - даже не то что более грубо, а именно подчеркивает примитивность говорящего сие - за счет жаргонности :> Пуританин - вот это подходит. 

"от, кто притворно набожен, добродетелен; лицемер." - каково бы ни было словарное определение - но очень часто в массах этот аспект именно лицемерия для именно "ханжи" - выпадает :> и слово становится просто синонимом пуританства

Comment: Olga, - нууу, это просто описания уже... это не термин... 

И, определенно, просится "моралОфаг", а не какой-то там "моралфаг"...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Есть такое слово — **моралист**.

Это именно человек, который напрягает, хотя при этом он может быть искренним.

Здесь у человека есть два признака: Первый, он добродетелен, а второй, он лезет другим людям в душу без мыла. Мне в русском языке неизвестно слово, охватывающее сразу оба признака (язык не считает, что они связаны).

Но - второй признак можно назвать "моралист" и это не вызовет явного конфликта с первым признаком, как в слове "ханжа". Моралист может не быть добродетелен, но может и быть. И тогда это добродетельный моралист. Наверное.

Мы такого человека не встречали, приводите - назовём его как-нибудь.

Comment: `Моралист` пока что звучит лучше всего. Но человека не приведу :)

Comment: Так как мораль бывает разная и не пуританская - это не сильно подходит. Это слишком обще, с одной стороны 
К тому же - это прежде всего некто почасту именно "читающий морали", произносящий сентенции на сию тему - конкретное такое значение узкое... С другой стороны... 
ханжа это намного шире - он может ничего и не вещать особо... 
Вообщем, не очень... - к тому же у "ханжа" намного более сильный негативный оттенок, чем у "моралист" - это не отрицательная оценка почти.

Answer (score 9):

Я бы сказал [*резонёр*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F0%E5%E7%EE%ED%B8%F0&all=x).

> Человек, любящий вести пространные рассуждения нравоучительного характера.

Примеры:

> Из живого, здорового полнотою чувства ребёнка делается рефлектер,
>   резонёр, умник, и, чем лучше он говорит о чувствах, тем беднее он
>   чувствами, ― чем умнее он на словах, тем пустее он внутренно. [В. Г.
>   Белинский. Общая риторика Н.Ф.Кошанского (1844)]
>
> Прежде всего, он был невероятно злобный зануда и резонер. [И. С.
>   Шкловский. Эшелон (1984) // «Химия и Жизнь», 1988-1992]

Comment: плюсую, отличный вариант мне кажется.

Comment: Очень интересное слово, но оно, мне кажется, не несет негативного смысла. Или все же несет?

Comment: @coverback Если оно не означает амплуа, то несёт. Вот что пишет Ушаков: 1.Человек, любящий вести пространные рассуждения, преимущ. нравоучительного характера.Нудный р.2.Традиционное действующее лицо в старой комедии, устами к-рого автор высказывает свои взгляды, нравоучения (лит.).3.Название соответствующего актерского амплуа.А как пьесы ставят... любовник — тенор, резонер — тенор и комик — тенор. А. Островский.

Comment: Да, резонёр имеет негативный смысл и достаточно подходит...

Answer (score 9):

Есть еще слово "святоша". Он может быть как лицемером, так и нет.

Answer (score 2):

Есть слово `прозелит`, оно очень близко к тому, что вы описываете, но есть один нюанс: Прозелит новообращён, он только что познал всю красоту правильного образа жизни (тяжёлого металла, христианства, ислама, буддизма - нужное подчеркнуть).

> [Прозелити́зм](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) (от прозелит, из лат. proselytus «обращённый», от греч. προσήλυτος «обращённый, нашедший своё место»):
>   1) стремление распространить свою веру, обратить других в свою веру, стремление к повсеместному установлению поддерживаемой религии,
>   2) перен. горячая преданность вновь принятому учению, новым убеждениям.

Есть слово `миссионер`, оно тоже носит ярко выраженный религиозный характер, но, опять-таки, в каких-то случаях похоже на ваш словесный фоторобот. 
Отсюда же синонимы - проповедник.

Так же смотрите `адвокат` (адвокат семейных ценностей), `ръяный сторонник`, `активный пропагандист`. C прилагательным `искренний`, которое ва сами же упомянули, ещё точней, например - искренний пропагандист вегетарианства.

В каких-то контекстах `непритворный` может быть подходящей и даже удачной заменой прилагательному `искренний`.

Так, ну а напоследок я должен напомнить, что мы должны быть подобны натуралистам, беспристрастно рассматривающим разных тварюшек под микроскопом, так что обсценная лексика тоже должна быть упомянута.

> Пётр, ты `заёбщик` просто!

или

> Иннокентий, какой же ты `мозгоёб` c этой своею моралью...

Comment: это слово с другим значением.

Comment: и все остальные тут - тоже :> максимум - как метафоры лишь могут тут использоваться

Answer (score -1):

Можно сказать, что такой человек находится с состоянии *прелести*, *прельщëн*. Такое значение слова "прелесть" распространено в правосланом христианстве.
Возможно такой человек является *неофтом*. *Неофит* - это любой недавно увероваший человек. У большинства таких людей вера ещë не окрепла, поэтому они могут находиться в состоянии *прелести*. Хотя в редких случаях вера *неофита* изначально крепка.

Answer (score -2):

Ханжой. Пуританином. Святошей. Филистером.

Резонёр вот, да.

Comment: В целом  как правило если ответ по сравнению с уже данными не добавляет ничего нового - он с большой вероятностью будет заминусован.

Comment: он добавляет очень правильное  тут слово - "Пуританин".